# Cannot import a module in parent directory

Tags: python, ubuntu, virtualenv, python-3.6

I am trying to get a python project working in Ubuntu 17, but I'm having trouble with module loading. I've been able to isolate the problem with a trivial example. This example works in Windows 10, but not in Ubuntu. Help getting this to work would be greatly appreciated!

Here are the steps I am following:

First I create a project directory called code_playground in ~/dev. Next I create a virtualenv for this project:

```
~/dev$ which virtualenv
/usr/local/bin/virtualenv

~/dev$ virtualenv -p python3.6 code_playground/
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python3.6
Using base prefix '/usr'
New python executable in /home/user/dev/code_playground/bin/python3.6
Also creating executable in /home/user/dev/code_playground/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
```

I activate the virtual environment:

```
~/dev/code_playground$ source ./bin/activate
(code_playground) ~/dev/code_playground$
```

It seems to work:

```
(code_playground) ~/dev/code_playground$ which python
/home/user/dev/code_playground/bin/python
```

I create a file called mod_a.py with a simple function in it:

```
def print_name(name):
    print('Your name is {0}'.format(name))
```

Now I create a subdirectory called sub :

```
(code playground) ~/dev/code_playground$ mkdir sub
(code playground) ~/dev/code_playground$ cd sub
(code playground) ~/dev/code_playground/sub$
```

Inside sub, I create a file called mod_b.py with these contents:

```
from mod_a import print_name

print_name('Joe')
```

I try to run mod_b.py, but I get an error:

```
(code playground) ~/dev/code_playground/sub$ python mod_b.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "mod_b.py", line 1, in <module>
      from mod_a import print_name
ImportError: No module named mod_a
```

Comment: Add  `import sys` and `print(sys.path)` at the begining of your script... and check the paths. But, most likely you'll have to `export PYTHONPATH=~/dev/code_playground:${PYTHONPATH}`, before starting _python_.

Comment: Thank you @CrisiFati. That does fix the problem. I wonder, do you have any insight as to why this is needed in Linux, but works without it in Windows? After virtualenv, but before setting the PYTHONPATH variable, here is what I get for sys.path from mod_b.py:

    `['/home/user/dev/code_playground/sub', 
    '/home/user/dev/code_playground/lib/python36.zip', 
    '/home/user/dev/code_playground/lib/python3.6', 
    '/home/user/dev/code_playground/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', 
    '/usr/lib/python3.6', 
    '/home/user/dev/code_playground/lib/python3.6/site-packages']`

Comment: I just noticed that in Windows, the code_playground directory is included in sys.path after running virtualenv, without having to set PYTHONPATH. However, this is not the case in Linux. I guess that's why it works in Windows. @CristiFati (or anyone else), do you happen to have any insight as to why that is?

Comment: You should `print(sys.path)` in _Win_ as well. Are you sure you followed the same steps on both *OS*es? Note there are some small differences regarding paths for _Python_ between _Win_ and _Ux_. Also, _VEnv_ might have smth to do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python interpreter has to know where to find `module_a.py`. The fact that the file that is importing the module `module_a.py` is in a sub-directory for the directory where `module_a.py` exist, "is not a thing that help much". You can try few things:

1- Add your `mod_a.py` path (before the script run) to your Python's path as suggested by @CristiFati.

2- Add your `mod_a.py` path (using Python code) to your Python's path doing something like (nasty one):

```
import
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/user/dev/code_playground/bin/python')
from mod_a import print_name
...
```

3- Evaluate relative imports ([6.4.2. Intra-package References](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references))

Comment: This solution actually works even without virtualenv, what if we want to take advantage of virtualenv without appending parent folder path explicitely ?  like Pycharm for example it initilizes  the sys path with project folder path automatically.